# How to ignore missing class compilation error in groovy/Java?

Tags: java, groovy, compiler-errors

I have a groovy script that is using a class (MyClass) object as shown below.

```
def myclass = new org.somename.com.processor.MyClass()
```

The script can work well even if the myclass object is null. There are some possibilities where the system can be started without the jar dependency which has MyClass.java class. In such cases, I just want to log a message and continue ignoring any compilation error. I could not handle the missing class error with try-catch as it is a compilation error. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Currently Im gettting this groovy error.

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
site:/path/to/file.groovy: 20: unable to resolve class org.somename.com.processor.MyClass
 @ line 20, column 9.
     myclass = new org.somename.com.processor.MyClass()
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Regards,
Shamran

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
def myclass = new org.somename.com.processor.MyClass()
```

You could do something like this:

```
def myclass

try {
    def theClass = Class.forName('org.somename.com.processor.MyClass')
    myclass = theClass.newInstance()
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // log your message
}
```

Alternatively, something like this should work:

```
def myclass

try {
    def theClass = 'org.somename.com.processor.MyClass' as Class
    myclass = theClass.newInstance()
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
   // log your message
}
```